# Download webpage source to a string in Perl

Tags: perl

How do I do it?

I would also like to use a proxy. How do I do that?

Comment: I think you'd get some more attention to this question if you provided some code of what you have so far.

Comment: @Pat: I don't have anything relevant. I'm looking for a small snippet that does one thing, there is no code I could provide that would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get("http://foo.com/bar");
my $content = $mech->res()->content();
```

For the proxy, see [the Mechanize FAQ](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFAQ#How-do-I-use-WWW%3a%3aMechanize-through-a-proxy-server-).